# new line character not working in sms api URL

Tags: api, authentication, sms, utility

I am integrating logon utility for shooting the messages from my PHP code, but unfortunately, I am facing issue with my SMS string. The new line characters are not working, although I have used '\n' and '%0A'.

Comment: try with %0d%0a

Comment: Its working, Thnx for the response.